# Laravel 5.6 authentication redirect issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've changed redirection URL `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in `LoginController.php` [as it written in docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart) but Laravel still redirects to default `/home` URL after login.

I thought login/authentication is easy out of the box in Laravel but still can't find where to configure it, unfortunately there is no comprehensive manual or tutorial for this purpose.

How to change redirection URL for login procedure properly and why it still redirects to the `/home` URL?

Comment: Did you add a `redirectTo()` method to `/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` as indicated by the docs?

Comment: @Mike, No, because there is no full path of this middleware described in the docs and I didn't have even a clue where to search this freaking redirect method. Thanks, you helped me out!

Comment: All of the HTTP middleware is in the `/app/Http/Middleware` directory.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks a lot, now I know it, but docs shouldn't be simplified to prevent searching manually the entire framework for just a one filename...

Comment: Maybe you need a better text editor that will help you search through the directory tree faster. I watched [this series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017), (which I would highly recommend for beginners btw), and the speaker uses Sublime editor, which is super fast at searching for files by name, essentially as fast as you can type it in.